# Button changes in 12.3

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, style, button, version-12.3

In the new 12.3 version I noticed a change in how buttons react to the `Background` option. For instance, take

```
Button["Button 1"]
Button["Button 2", Background -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5]]
```

[image]

Not only a thick boundary is formed, but it also seems that the text is slightly off-center. Any ideas on how to fix this and simply get

[image]

Comment: Does `Button["Button 2", Background -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5], Appearance -> "Frameless", FrameMargins -> 5]` do what you want?

Comment: @BobHanlon `FrameMargins -> 3` seems to be more suitable. But couldn't we make it to be the default size somehow? Really nice answer nonetheless, didn't think of using that option.

Comment: To change the defaults put `SetOptions[Button, Appearance -> "Frameless", FrameMargins -> 3];` into an [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file